# How to build a button to click on and play / stop an audio?

Tags: javascript, html, image, audio, playback

i want to build a image button, that plays an audio.
My Version works but when I want to use it more than once on a site, it only play one mp3, not the other ones.

My Code:

```
<audio loop="false" src="audio_01.mp3">&nbsp;</audio>

<p><img alt="" class="hover_pic" src="image.png" style="width: 40%;cursor:pointer" /></p>
<script>
  var aud = document.getElementById("ASong").children[0];
  var isPlaying = false;
  aud.pause();

  function playPause() {
    if (isPlaying) {
      aud.pause();
    } else {
      aud.play();
    }
    isPlaying = !isPlaying;
  }
</script></div>
```

and

```
<div id="BSong" onclick="playPause()" type="button">
<audio loop="false" src="audio_02.mp3">&nbsp;</audio>

<p><img alt="" class="hover_pic" src="image.png" style="width: 40%;cursor:pointer" /></p>
<script>
  var aud = document.getElementById("BSong").children[0];
  var isPlaying = false;
  aud.pause();

  function playPause() {
    if (isPlaying) {
      aud.pause();
    } else {
      aud.play();
    }
    isPlaying = !isPlaying;
  }
</script></div>
```

So you have an idea what the problem is that the button only play one of them on the website?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same variable names multiple times like aud, isPlayig, etc..

To solve this issue, you should declare only once the whole script and form the onclick="playPause()" send the id of the song you want to play.

Be aware if there is already some music which is playing.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell how your two current code snippets are arranged with respect to each other, but duplicating the code over and over every time you want to add another track is going to be unmaintainable. As it stands, the variables for `isPlaying` and `aud` probably overwrite each other, depending on how they're laid out, even if they're in different scripts. Using `const` or `let` instead of `var` and `use strict;` at the top of your script can help detect these aliases.

You could add closures around each one to keep them distinct, but a better approach is to write a loop (which also acts as a scoping closure) and dynamically add the listener to each element. For example:

```js
const trackEls = [...document.querySelectorAll(".track")];

for (const trackEl of trackEls) {
  const audioEl = trackEl.querySelector("audio");
  trackEl.addEventListener("click", () => {
    audioEl.paused ? audioEl.play() : audioEl.pause();
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="tracks">
  <div type="button" class="track">
    <audio src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d8/Bourne_woods_2020-11-18_0732.mp3"></audio>
    <img alt="play track icon" src="https://picsum.photos/50/50" class="track-icon">
  </div>
  <div type="button" class="track">
    <audio src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ea/Rapid-Acoustic-Survey-for-Biodiversity-Appraisal-pone.0004065.s017.ogg"></audio>
    <img alt="play track icon" src="https://picsum.photos/50/50" class="track-icon">
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that the above code lets multiple audio files play at once. If you want to stop all other audio elements when a new one is clicked and reset their time, you can do that with a loop or an extra variable that keeps track of the currently-playing track. For example:

```js
const trackEls = [...document.querySelectorAll(".track")];
let currentTrack;

for (const trackEl of trackEls) {
  const audioEl = trackEl.querySelector("audio");
  trackEl.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (audioEl !== currentTrack) {
      if (currentTrack) {
        currentTrack.pause();
        currentTrack.currentTime = 0;
      }

      currentTrack = audioEl;
    }

    audioEl.paused ? audioEl.play() : audioEl.pause();
  });  
}
```

```html
<div class="tracks">
  <div type="button" class="track">
    <audio src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d8/Bourne_woods_2020-11-18_0732.mp3"></audio>
    <img alt="play track icon" src="https://picsum.photos/50/50" class="track-icon">
  </div>
  <div type="button" class="track">
    <audio src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ea/Rapid-Acoustic-Survey-for-Biodiversity-Appraisal-pone.0004065.s017.ogg"></audio>
    <img alt="play track icon" src="https://picsum.photos/50/50" class="track-icon">
  </div>
</div>
```

A few remarks on your code:

- There's no need for `isPlaying` variables since `audio` elements already track their playing/paused state with `audioElement.paused`. If you track it in external state, you add further complication and room for bugs if your variable and the the audio element's state go out of sync.
- Avoid putting a `<script>` in a `<div>`. `<script>` is usually a child of `<body>` or `<head>` (probably `<body>` in this case), after all of the HTML tags are closed.
- `onclick` on an HTML element is generally poor practice. HTML should be structural, not behavioral. Similarly, `style="width: 40%;cursor:pointer"` should be moved to an external stylesheet and applied to a class.
- `.children[0];` is a brittle way to select the audio element in a track. If you wind up rearranging elements in the div, this code is liable to break. `document.querySelector("#BSong audio")` is more precise and robust to refactors, although using classes instead of ids enables easier dynamism so you don't have to type each track out by hand.
- CSS classes are usually kebab-case, so `hover_pic` would be `hover-pic`.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I learn a lot but I am only a graphic designer how try to solve the problems from her boss. Your code works quite well, but I have to refresh the page before it plays. It could be a problem from the website. I dont know.

Comment: What do you mean by "I have to refresh the page before it plays"?

Comment: The Sound doesnt play when i open the website and klick on the button. I have to reload the current page first, then it plays.

Comment: Do you mean my mock website or yours? If yours only, I'm not really sure how to reproduce that problem -- you might need to add context to your post. Is there some persistent state in local storage or something that might make the behavior different from one load to the next? Is the cache stale? Otherwise, I'd imagine it'd be the same thing on every load.

Comment: no, it's on my website, so it's probably in the programming on the website. Thanks for your detailed help! I ask someone who can program it directly into my cms system. Thank you.