# How can I pause or stop the audio in this working script?

Tags: javascript

This is a working script for start to play the desired audio.
Could anybody tell good a good solution for pause or stop the audio by clicking on the onclick paragraph again?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="hu">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=script, initial-scale=sript">
<title>English Homonyms</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    
<script type="text/javascript">

function play(param) {

const playlist = [
"0 => nincs",
"audio/audio_01.mp3",
"audio/audio_02.mp3",
"audio/audio_03.mp3"
];

var list = param;
var music = playlist[param];

var audio = new Audio(music);
audio.play();
}

</script>

</head>
<body>

<h1>ENGLISH PRONUNCIATON NONSENSES – HOMONYMS</h1>

<p onclick = "play(1)">1. The bandage was wound around the wound.</p>
<p onclick = "play(2)">2. The farm was used to produce produce.</p>
<p onclick = "play(3)">3. The dump was so full that it had to refuse more refuse.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is rather broad; there are many ways to go about it, but [How to build a button to click on and play / stop an audio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71223019/how-to-build-a-button-to-click-on-and-play-stop-an-audio/71225731#71225731) might help (use paragraphs instead of images). You probably want to initialize your array outside of the function, keep track of the currently-playing index, then toggle `allAudio[currentTrack].pause()` / `.play()` in the listeners based on the `.paused` boolean.

Comment: given that you used `Audio` element already, why dont you embed the audio properly? something like `<audio controls src="audio/audio_01.mp3">` to replace the `p` onclick thing. the browser will take care play and pause button for you.

Comment: Bagus Tesa, I know you are right but I had the purpose to find a solution without using the embedded audio player. I did it before but I did not like it therefore I looked for a simpler solution. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let nowPlaying = 0
let nowAudio = new Audio()

function play(param) {
    const playlist = [
        "0 => nincs",
        "audio/audio_01.mp3",
        "audio/audio_02.mp3",
        "audio/audio_03.mp3",
    ];

    var lista = param;
    var zene = playlist[param];

    if (nowPlaying === param) {
        if (nowAudio.paused) {
            nowAudio.play()
        } else {
            nowAudio.pause()
        }
    } else {
        nowAudio = new Audio(zene);
        nowAudio.play();

        nowPlaying = param
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain to OP *how* your code solves his problem.